# How to retrieve the number of rows in a table

Tags: database, visual-c++, mfc

I am trying to retrieve the number of rows in a table but no matter the number i always get 1 as the result.

Here is the code:

```
UpdateData(TRUE);
CDatabase database;
CString connectionstring, sqlquery, Slno,size,portno,header,id;
connectionstring=TEXT("Driver={SQL NATIVE CLIENT};SERVER=CYBERTRON\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=packets;Trusted_Connection=Yes" );
database.Open(NULL, FALSE, FALSE, connectionstring);
CRecordset set(&database);
sqlquery.Format(TEXT("select * from allpacks;"));
set.Open(CRecordset::forwardOnly, sqlquery, NULL);
int x=set.GetRecordCount();
CString temp;
temp.Format("%d",x);
AfxMessageBox(temp);
;
```

Comment: Please put a little more effort into your question. Have you tried using a debugger?

Comment: ummmmm sry i guess im kinda a newbie anyway my program connects to a database and retrieves rows from it, int x=set.GetRecordCount() is supposed to retrieve the number of rows in the result set after it performs select * from allpacks but when i try to display the number x it always displays 1 even though i manually add 3-4 rows

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you read the [documentation for GetRecordCount()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w9109302%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)?

> The record count is maintained
>   as a "high water mark," the
>   highest-numbered record yet seen as
>   the user moves through the records.
>   The total number of records is only
>   known after the user has moved beyond
>   the last record. For performance
>   reasons, the count is not updated when
>   you call MoveLast. To count the
>   records yourself, call MoveNext
>   repeatedly until IsEOF returns
>   nonzero. Adding a record via
>   CRecordset:AddNew and Update increases
>   the count; deleting a record via
>   CRecordset::Delete decreases the
>   count.

You're not moving through the rows.

Now, if you actually tried to count rows in one of my tables that way, I'd hunt you down and poke you in the eye with a sharp stick. Instead, I'd usually expect you to use SQL like this:

```
select count(*) num_rows from allpacks;
```

That SQL statement will always return one row, having a single column named "num_rows".